# java input string and stop when 'stop' is entered

Tags: java, loops

this is my code and I have a do-while loop which should carry on unless the string "text" entered is "stop". However when I compile the code it doesnt stop and stuck in an infinite loop. Pease help. Thanks.

```
import java.io.*;

public class input
{
    public static void main(String[] argv) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));  
        String text = "";  
        do
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter a string: ");
            text = br.readLine(); 
            System.out.println(text);
        }
        while (text != "stop");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing `text != "stop"` by `!text.equals("stop")`

`!=` is a reference equality test, `.equals()` is a logical equality test. Two strings can be different objects and still be logicaly equals (same content in this case).

Comment: To be more specific; `!=` operator compares references in case of reference types whereas for primitives it compares values (i.e. performs logical comparison)

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing strings with `!=`. That does not work in Java. You should use `equals()` to compare strings:

```
while (!text.equals("stop"));
```

Note that `==` and `!=` on objects compare the *references* - i.e., if you use those operators on non-primitive variables, you are checking if the variables refer to the same object, and not if the content of those objects is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
while (text != "stop")
```

with

```
while (!text.equals("stop"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compare strings using `==`. Use `equals`: `while(!"stop".equals(text))`.

Also since it comes from the user input, you might want to compare ignoring the case, you can use `equalsIgnoreCase`.

Answer (score 0):

All posters are right: you should use String.equals().

Also you should complete understand String handling in Java. You will need it everywhere.

Even that String.equals should be used Java offers some "magic", that works even with your comparison. Keep learning !

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String text = "";
        "stop".intern();
        do {
            System.out.println("Please enter a string: ");
            text = br.readLine().intern();
            System.out.println(text);
        } while (text != "stop");
    }
```

Comment: `"stop".intern()` is not required.